# Pods start to be in pending state too long

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cluster-computing

I have a cluster where jobs are created in order of what my users do.
Sometimes I can have 0 job in parallel and sometimes 20 to 100.
I have set the following limits for each container:

```
cpu limit: 512m
memory limit: 512Mi;
cpu request: 256m;
memroy request: 128Mi;
```

I have by default 2 nodes and each one has:

```
7.91 CPU allocable
10.16 GB allocable
```

The node pool can scale to 5 nodes max.

But when the cluster starts to have 8 and more jobs in parallel, the new jobs start to be in pending, waiting for other jobs to get down.
If a job is selected to start directly it will be completed in 6 to 7 seconds.
But when the cluster starts to struggle from 8 or 10 jobs, each job take approximately 20 seconds to be completed, because it blocked in pending state or in ContainerCreating state.

I have IfNotPresent as imagePullPolicy and each image has a version.

I suppose the cluster will start struggling with 28 jobs knowing my allocable resources, then creates a new node and so on.
Why am I wrong ?
Is it possible to force each container to start without the pending state ?
I have found a new scheduler, but i am not sure if it can help me poseidon-firmament-alternate-scheduler ?

Comment: Is imagePullPolicy for these pods set to "Always"? Are you using `latest` tag? Are you using different image for every job run? If to any of these questions you answered positively you are probably having issues resulting from network bottleneck.

Comment: @HelloWorld I have IfNotPresent as imagePullPolicy and each image has a version, so it's not about pulling the image each time.

Comment: Can you please describe in details how to replicate your issue?

Comment: Start N jobs with a container running javac and java with a class printing 5 things approximatively, with the resources i gave previously, You may separate each creation of the job with a random time (0 to 5 seconds) I forgot to mention but a configMap is mount for each Job. But never got the problem a job cannot be created because a configMap is missing.

Comment: I don't think this is a scheduling problem. I tried to schedule many jobs at the same time as you said and scheduler had no problems with it. The problem has to be somewhere else.

Comment: You're right, it's not the scheduler. It's the machine type, I was on a E2 instance, i test with N1 instance and i've got better result, didn't though first time. Thanks for your help